# Arrays of struct in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free, dynamic-arrays

```
struct a {
    int a;
    int b; 
};

struct a* ptr = NULL;
```

In main

```
ptr = malloc(5 * sizeof(struct a )); 
//assume is 5 is from user
```

Assign values to ptr[0].a and ptr[0].b, similarly to all 5 block

```
free(ptr);
```

Is free (ptr) enough to free all arrays of struct? Or should i free explicitly? If so, how?  Thanks.

Comment: you need to free when you explicitly allocate memory (malloc, calloc, realloc)

Comment: so,is free(ptr) enough in my case ? to free all arrays of struct?

Comment: Yes it is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to free whatever is returned by any memory management function. For allocations that are nested you need to do it reverse order of the way they are allocated. (Typical example would be creation of jagged array)

```
 void free(void *ptr);
```

From [7.22.3.2p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2)

> The free function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. ***Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined***.

In your case `free(ptr)` *would be enough to free* the dynamically allocated memory. If it contained some pointer variable to which we assigned address of dynamically allocated memory then you would need to free then first and then this `ptr` variable.

Comment: is free(ptr); enough in my case?

Comment: @bbcbbc1.: Yep. Edited answer. It is enough. ***Yes***.

Comment: @bbcbbc1.: if it helped select upvote the answer.